# Strategies to find associations between subset of variables

Tags: clustering, sparse, multiple-response

My post is more about ideas than one specific approach. My problem is pretty simple, I have simulated two matrices of noisy data, basically following correlated negative binomial distributions, and my main question here is how to retrieve associations that I know are true. I am in a context of benchmark of method for multi-omics data.

Since my data are mainly sparse (e.g., few associations between my variables of my two datasets) and have strong within-correlations, I applied Sparse PLS and regularized CCA in order to proceed to multidimensional shrinkage. Thus, I obtain loadings of variables on  the different components. If I plot these loadings on the two first components I have something like this :

[image]

From this, I would like to determine which variables (from X or Y) are associated with other variables from the other dataset. I firstly thought of clustering method with the assumption that elements within the same cluster are considered as associated. However, regardless of the method (EM clustering, K-Means, HClust etc...), performance is bad. It is worth noting that for the sPLS, I am able to remove variables with loadings equal to 0 on both components, which is not the case for rCCA.

So, I would be curious if you have any ideas about retrieving the associations. I am very open to general strategies but different methods should be considered as well. My sole criterion is to have something systematic with a minimum of arbitrary choices.

I would update the post with replicable example if needed.